# I can't capture ProcessingException when sending object instead of array

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jersey

I get a ProcessingException when I send an object instead of an array. I can't capture the ProcessingException not even with a javax.ws.rs.ext.ExceptionMapper< Exception >

I'm using jersey 2.25

```
@POST
@Path("/post")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response testInJSON(Test[] test) {

    String result = "Test message : " + test[0].getTest();  
    return Response.status(Response.Status.ACCEPTED).entity(result).build();

}
```

POM.XML

```
<properties>
    <jersey2.version>2.25</jersey2.version>
    <jaxrs.version>2.0.1</jaxrs.version>
    <tomcat.version>7.0.69</tomcat.version> 
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <!-- JAX-RS -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        <version>${jaxrs.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Jersey -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey2.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey2.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey2.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

stacktrace:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:144)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:161)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:160)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:308)
```

**Test.java**

```
public class Test implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String test;
    public String getTest() {
        return test;
    }
    public void setTest(String test) {
        this.test = test;
    }
}
```

UPDATE:
It seems to be a framework bug. a Jira has been opened. https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-3222

Comment: Are you using Jackson as the JSON provider?

Comment: yes, I'm using jackson as my default provider

Answer (score 1):

ProcessingException handling is covered by ResponseErrorMapper, not by ExceptionMapper:

```
public class MyExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<Throwable>, ResponseErrorMapper {
    ...
```

to make it working, you need to set 'PROCESSING_RESPONSE_ERRORS_ENABLED' property on your app config:

```
val config = ResourceConfig()
config.register(new MyExceptionMapper(...))
config.setProperties(new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>() {{
    put(org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerProperties.PROCESSING_RESPONSE_ERRORS_ENABLED, true);
}});
```